# How can I run both python apps?

Tags: python

I have to apps which depend on each other. Both are part of the same project:

1. app.py - that supports interaction with the user
2. download.py - that supports sending and receiving files

How can I run both using terminal (or PyCharm)?

Comment: tried opening two terminals and running one in each?

Comment: How exactly do they _depend_ on each other?

Comment: In app.py... `from download import *`, then use its functions like normal

Comment: one of them is on the server side, and the second one - on the client side. Both codes have app = Flask(__name__), and they have app.run - i've set app.run(port='5555') for one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either run these two commands in separate terminals:

```
python app.py
python download.py
```

Or run this command in a single terminal (`&` means "run in background"):

```
python app.py & python download.py
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash `&&` operator if first one is needed to finish succesfuly then run second one.

```
python app.py && python download.py
```